# Executar "Procv" em um Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um Dataframe em pandas contendo uma listagem com valores similares a estes:

```py
     a  e    r
0   88  6 -496
1    8  2 -188
2   76  5 -482
3   78  4   24
4   19  1 -346
5   40  1 -346
6   61  0 -224
7   79  1 -346
8   64  4   24
9   86  0 -224
10  47  1 -346
11  49  0 -224
```

Eu gostaria de executar uma procedimento similar ao "procv" do Excel para os valores da coluna `e` em relação a coluna `r` (filtrar os valores unicos da coluna e, verificar os valores correspondentes para a coluna r):
Por ex:

```
0 -224
1 -346
2 -188
4   24
5 -482
6 -496
```

encontrar os valores unicos de `e` eu consigo via:

```py
df['e'].unique()
```

mas não estou conseguindo filtrar os valores de `r` e gerar um dataframe com os resultados.

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para data.frames o método para tirar dados repetidos de uma coluna é `drop.duplicates()`. E `sort_values()` para deixar os valores na ordem crescente de uma coluna.

```
nova_df = df[['e','r']].drop_duplicates('e').sort_values('e')
```

Com isso o resultado já vem em outra data frame.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!